# Cannot disable debugger with Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

My app runs really slow with Xcode 4.5, and i just realized it's due the debugger always on.
It seems you can't select NONE under Manage Schema/Release/Debugger, so how can you disable debugger on Xcode 4.5?

many thanks in advance

Comment: i meant the debugger is always on on REAL device. Running with simulator there is no problem because i can disable the debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at this answer - does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922408/can-i-disable-the-debugger-in-xcode-4

Comment: thank you for the quick replay. I know that is possible to disable the debugger from edit schema but when i have upgraded to XCode 4.5 it seems the options NONE Debugger is disappeared when running on real device.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the slowness is due to the debugger being attached. It is more likely that the slowness is due to compiling in Debug rather than Release mode. Debug does not optimize the code. Release does. You can switch your configuration to Release and it should speed up, but be more difficult to debug. You can create separate Debug and Release schemes if you like.

Note that the specific difference in Debug and Release that matters here is the compiler optimization. Debug passes "-O0". Release passes "-Os". You could of course create a Debug configuration that passes "-Os" without changing other things (like turning off assertions, if your Release configuration does that).

Comment: it is already set to release mode and it is slow. The strange thing is that i have only 2 options on debugger: GDB and LLDB. The NONE option disappear when i build on real device.