# Adding a build configuration in Xcode

Tags: configuration, build, xcode5

I'd like to add a new build configuration in Xcode 5, "QA", to the other three we currently have (Debug, Distribution, Release). However, when I click "Editor > Add Configuration", everything is grayed out. I'm not very familiar with Xcode in the first place, so I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Is there a reason it's grayed out? Is this this process to add a build configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Here it is an article may be it will help you guys. Here you will see the sample code + in details how you can set your staging and release web urls, keys and much more using build configurations. I saw various resources but there was not a sample of full code. Thats why i have added the full sample code with detail description of how you can generate set build configurations using plist and automated process of build configurations, while creating archive for release and testing mode. https://github.com/ourangzeb/Build-Configuration-for-IOS

Comment: The [excellent selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882062/2547229) seems to be relevant only for now quite old versions of Xcode. For recent Xcode versions [there is another excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59134606/2547229). Would it make sense to amend the accepted answer to be appropriate for the current Xcode?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For Xcode 11 +  , you can add your custom configuration here:

[image]

Comment: That's also true for earlier Xcode versions. You don't need to use the menu bar (I didn't even realize you could before finding this question)

Answer (score 299):

I ran into this same problem and figured it out.  Here is a screenshot of the problem.  I want to duplicate my "Release" configuration, but the option to do so is disabled.  Why?

[image]

The answer is hiding behind this little button here (circled in red)...

[image]

This menu will open to reveal that you currently have a build target selected.  Build targets don't have their own configurations.

Configurations are project-wide. If you **select the project file**, the menu will work, as shown here.

You also have to **make sure that the 'Info' tab is selected**, the options are still greyed out if you are on the 'Build Settings' page

[image]

Comment: You also have to make sure that the 'Info' tab is selected, the options are stil greyed out if you are on the 'Build Settings' page

Comment: "Editor (!) menu", then select Info, then select Project... Apple, why this simple thing require people to ask questions on SO?

Comment: I followed this answer *exactly* (YES, I've selected by project as in the screenshot, YES, I selected Info tab THEN my project) but all those options are still greyed out?

Comment: For me it was working only when I pressed "Build Settings" tab. However, you can scroll "Build Settings" down to "User-Defined" section and add setting manually.

Comment: what a bad UX that is. You really have to make sure all those tiny things align properly to enabled those menu items.

Comment: Yes, it's 99% of learning xcode - all those tiny little icons under which so much is hidden.

Answer (score 4):

**Build Configuration and Build Configuration File(.xcconfig)**

It allows you to manage `Build Settings`. It is actually what you see when reviewing `Build Settings` and it's mirrors(like `Signing` in `Signing & Capabilities`)

[image]

```
Build Configuration(e.g. Release/Debug) -> Build Configuration File(.xcconfig) or some default config file
```

[[Xcode structure]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)

**Build Configuration**

Actually `Debug`/`Release` Build Configurations are created by default

**Create Build Configuration**

You are able to create a new Build Configuration via duplicating an existing(Debug/Release) in `Configurations`

```
Editor -> Add Configuration -> Duplicate <configuration_name> Configuration -> Click plus button under configuration list
//Set a name - Experiments for example
```

[image]

**Select Build Configuration**

```
Scheme -> Info -> Build Configuration
```

**Build Configuration File(.xcconfig)**

Much more powerful feature is `build configuration file`  which you can assign for your `configuration`

```
File -> New -> File... -> Configuration Settings File
//Do not include it to any target

Project -> Info -> Configurations -> Build Configuration -> Target -> Build Configuration File
```

[image]

Please note that you are able to set Build Configuration File for **Project** and for **Target**. Depends on it **Resolved** variable will be set, also `$(inherited)`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67370410/4770877) will be different

For example add name into `Build Configuration File`

```
PRODUCT_NAME = THE BEST NAME
```

The result you can find on `Build Settings`

[image]
`CocoaPods` and `Build Configuration File`

```
project '<project_name>', '<scheme_name_1>' => :<build_congiguration_file_name_1>
//For example
project 'MyProject', 'debug' => :conf1, 'release' => :conf2
```

Build Configuration File(.xcconfig). You can use next syntax to add or override the parent parameters

```
#include "<path_to_xcconfig>"
```