# creating a static library for both OSX and IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode8, static-libraries

I want to create with xCode a static library project that will be used by IOS and OSX applications. My wish is to have a single porject/target and 2 different build configurations, so when I want to build for IOS I'll pick one, and when I want to do it for OSX I'll pick the other.

My first guess was creating a macOS static library target and then add a build configuration for IOS ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842746/adding-a-build-configuration-in-xcode) you can find an explanation how), but I'm a bit afraid I'll miss some configuration options in the future.

Another option is to create a new target for IOS (Cocoa touch static library), which will use the same source files

I've also found an [old article](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/) suggesting a different solution: "Static Libraries and Cross-Project References", but I'm not sure if it's still relevant because it's from 2009.

Do you have any suggestions/tips/experiences which are relevant for such an issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?