# App is crashing when open it from test flight

Tags: testflight

[image]When app is open from test flight it shows only notification alert and it comes to background.If I open it from icon its working fine. Any one please tell me what will be the issue.

I got this when it install from test flight.

Comment: What is the second way you are opening app? This one 'from icon'? I guess you were debugging it, so app was installed and then you were able to open it from this 'icon'.

Comment: yes , second way is from icon

Comment: I am not an expert and haven't work with iOS app for a while, but what I think your debugging app is working, but not production. Try to remove app from your phone, make build from xcode and install it via iTunes. This way you will see if it will work this way. If app will work, then something is wrong with testflight. If not, then it is not testflight fault, but your build configuration.

Comment: This link might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842746/adding-a-build-configuration-in-xcode good luck.

Comment: It's not working I got same issue.